# How can I add a new block-box to my prestashop?

Tags: php, prestashop

I need to add a new block-box, upper the "contact" box in prestashop. It does need some logic (database), how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for creating a new module :
http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Creating+a+PrestaShop+module